# Logarithm Matlab

Tags: matlab, logarithm

I try to use the logarithm function to a specific base in Matlab but I get the error message: 
"Error using log
Too many input arguments." which I do not understand because the syntax is very simple. 
 My code is: log(4,2);
Why do I get this error?

Comment: Are you looking for [`log2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log2.html)?

Answer (score 2):

matlab's `log` function (before R2017a) doesn't have this functionality.
instead, you can do: `log(x)/log(n)`, whereas [`log_n(x) = log(x)/log(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)

Comment: Just a remark: MATLAB R2017a does have this functionality (https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/log.html). But probably @gamma uses an earlier version.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working now but i still get an error when I'm trying to plot the function. My code is 
b = [1/10, 1/exp(1),1/2,2,exp(1),10]
x = 0.1:0.1:4.5;
[B,X] = meshgrid(b,x)
g = log(X)/log(B);
plot(X,g)

I get the message: Error using plot. Vectors must be the same length. I don't quite understand this because since g is defined on x, g and x should have the same length.

Comment: First, consider using ./ rather than / when computing g. Second, g is defined on X, not on x so it's a matrix, not a vector.

Comment: What do you mean with ./rather than/? Right, g is a Matrix but why do I get this error? I have plotted the same Data with the power function and it works perfect. So I don't understand my mistake!

Comment: @MiriamFarber That's only for mupad.

Comment: @gamma If you're having a different problem, please ask it as a new question.

Comment: I just assume you are interested in element-wise division, which is `./`. if you use `g = log(X)./log(B);` the code works